# Show that a function is radial iff it is rotation invariant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, orthogonal-matrices

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R$.

Remember that $f$ is called *radial* if $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y\in\Omega$ with $\|x\|=\|y\|$. Let $O(d)$ denote the orthogonal group of dimension $d$.

> How can we show that $f$ is radial iff $f=f\circ\left.U\right|_\Omega$ for all $U\in O(d)$?

The first implication is easy to show: If $f$ is radial and $U\in O(d)$, then $f(x)=(f\circ U)(x)$ for all $x\in\Omega$, since $\|Ux\|=\|x\|$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$.

However, I don't know how we can establish the other implication. So, how can we do it?

(I've only seen the claim in the special case $\Omega=B_r(0)$ for some $r>0$. I don't think that this particular setting is important, but since I'm failing to show the other implication, feel free to restrict to this case, if I'm wrong and this is necessary.)

Comment: We do need $\Omega$ to be $O(d)$-invariant, so if $\Omega$ is connected then $\Omega$ is either a ball or the shell between two fixed radii. <> The key point is, if $f = f \circ U$ for all $U$, then $f$ is constant on orbits of $O(d)$, a.k.a. level sets of the norm.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang How precisely do you define $O(d)$-invariant and how can we show that a ball is $O(d)$-invariant? If you simply mean that $U\Omega=\Omega$, then it's clear to me that this is satisfied when $\Omega$ is a ball, but I still don't see why this yields the claim.

Comment: A set $\Omega$ is "$O(d)$-invariant" if $U(\Omega) \subset \Omega$ for all $U$ in $O(d)$, i.e., each orthogonal matrix maps $\Omega$ into (and hence onto) itself. This implies $\Omega$ is a union of spheres centered at the origin. <> The key sub-point may be: If $x$ and $y$ are elements of $\mathbf{R}^{d}$, then there exists an orthogonal matrix $U$ with $y = Ux$ _if and only if_ $\|x\| = \|y\|$.